# Replace symbolic links to libraries in executable with full path

Tags: macos, symlink, library

Because I use homebrew to manage my packages but I compile ffmpeg by myself (I need to enable some components that is not included in the homebrew build), when homebrew upgrades one of its formulas that is a dependency of ffmpeg dyld can't find the library. Because I set an environmental variable to disable homebrew cleaning old versions of formulas, the libraries are still there, just that the `/usr/local/opt/<formula>` path is linked to the new version in `/usr/local/cellar/<formula>/<new_version>`. How can I replace the symbolic links in the libraries ffmpeg links to with the full path? E.g. `/usr/local/opt/x264/lib/libx264.155.dylib` to `/usr/local/Cellar/x264/r2917_1/lib/libx264.155.dylib` I know I can use `install_name_tool`, but there are 151 libraries and 3 executables (`ffmpeg`, `ffprobe`, and `ffplay`) so it's very time-consuming to do it by hand.

Comment: You could build a script to call `install_name_tool` with the appropriate parameters, or link your self-built `ffmpeg` directly to `/usr/local/Cellar/x264/r2917_1/lib/...` when you are building it.

Comment: People think they should be using Homebrew but also think they shouldn't learn how it actually works.  The correct answer is to create your own tap for your custom ffmpeg the way Homebrew tells you to. https://docs.brew.sh/How-to-Create-and-Maintain-a-Tap

Comment: @nohillside I'm not sure how to link `ffmpeg` directly to the library. What I do is just `make` and `gcc ...` for a couple of problematic files.

Comment: @joyJin  Homebrew won't let you do what?  How would they stop you?

Comment: @JoyJin You are choosing to completely ignore what I am saying and what Homebrew's documentation says.  You have fun with that.

Comment: @MarcWilson It seems like I don't actually know how Homebrew works so I will not continue the discussion. Thank you for mentioning to create a tap for custom ffmpeg.